# If div has no content hide other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following JS:

```
if ( $("#secretContent").children().length == 0) {
    $("#seemore").hide();
}​
```

and here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GVd9h/) demonstrating my questions. I have the intention of hiding the div with id "seemore" when the div with id "secretContent" has no children/contents.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doing the trick http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/9Jmug/1/

```
if ( $("#secretContent").children().length < 1) {
    $("#seemore").hide();
}​
```

in the fiddle it shows the content because it has an aditional div inside secretContent

Comment: I cant see how in my example this works. When you remove the contents of the div of id secretContent, and then run, the div with id seemore stays shown and does not hide?

Comment: That works, but it doesn't show it when there is actually content in the div

Comment: No, when you delete the text in the first div, the second div is still shown

Comment: what browser are you using? In chrome 17 works fine. Also IE8 and Firefox 11. You are trying to hide the 'seemore' div when 'secretContent' has no children or text inside?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10401/discussion-between-chepe263-and-jacktheripper)

Answer (score 4):

So... You want to replace that `> 0` with `== 0`, I think.

Comment: No, I meant `==`. `children()` always returns an integer, and `0` is very obviously an integer. There is absolutely no need to waste a byte on an extra `=` sign.

Comment: Waste a WHOLE BYTE? How can anyone deal with that overhead!?

Comment: I cant see how in my example this works. When you remove the contents of the div of id secretContent, and then run, the div with id seemore stays shown and does not hide?

Comment: @Kolink do you always use `== 0` to check if something is `false`? Because that saves **FOUR** bytes!

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Nope, I use `if( !condition)` - saving seven over `== false` ;)

Comment: Type coercion using the comparison operators `==` and `!=` is bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

Probably want to change you "greater than" to an equal:

```
if ( $("#secretContent").children().length == 0) {
    $("#seemore").hide();
}​
```

As Vega suggests, if you care about text nodes, and not strictly children HTML elements, then you need to use `contents()` in place of `children`:

```
if ( $("#secretContent").contents().length == 0) {
    $("#seemore").hide();
}​
```

Here is a demo showing both:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/NASQn/

**Note!** It should be noted that `.contents()` counts **any** text inside of the `div`.

This:

```
<div>
</div>
```

and this:

```
<div> </div>
```

Are both considered **not empty** because the first has a newline, and the second has a space, which are both considered text nodes.  The only thing that is considered empty when using `.contents()` is this:

```
<div></div>
```

If you want to account for this, you need to check for no `children()` and then see if the remaining text is only whitespace:

```
if ( $("#secretContent").children().length == 0) {
    if( $("#secretContent").text().match(/^\s*$/) ) {
        $("#seemore").hide();
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/4xtME/

Comment: You are probably looking for @Vega's suggestion then.  If you care about text content, you need to change `children()` to `content()` as well.

Comment: @jacktheripper Your jsFiddle has text content. Do you want to hide if there are some contents/children?

Comment: I cant see how in my example this works. When you remove the contents of the div of id secretContent, and then run, the div with id seemore stays shown and does not hide?

Comment: See my update above.  My guess is that you are leaving white-space in `#secretContent`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `.contents` instead of `.children` incase if you want to check for text content too. Also changed the `>` to `==`. Try and let me know,

```
if ( $("#secretContent").contents().length == 0) {
    $("#seemore").hide();
}​
```

Comment: @jacktheripper What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

replace " > 0 " with "== 0"

That should do the trick!